# Could not retrive data from internet in android

Tags: android, networking

I use this for connecting to internet and retrieve page source, very simply :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_library);
    String data = "";

    if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        tv.setText("No Connection!!!");
        return;
    }

    try{
        URL url = null;
        url = new URL("http://google.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            data += line;
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        tv.setText(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        tv.setText("error : "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

but data doesn't come back from internet.
what's the problem?

Comment: ue a thread os asynctask. no network operation on ui thread

Comment: have you tried to debug your app?

Comment: @Raghunandan , isn't it possible to have internet connection on main thread ? i have seen it in a tutorial !

Comment: @nikis , i have tried debugging but i didn't get any point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your code that retrieves data from the internet, in a background task, so either in a Service or an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
if(!isNetworkAvailable()){

    tv.setText("No Connection!!!");
    new ChangePasswordAsyncTask().execute();
    return;
}


private class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private String data;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        try
        {
            // do stuff from server
                  URL url = null;
                  url = new URL("http://google.com");
                 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                  String line = "";
                 while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                     data += line;
                 }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // String jData = "";
        try
        {
            // set UI on this method

               tv.setText(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Toast.makeText(context, jMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that find view by id can't be used in an async task!

Comment: connect to server is a seperated class ? so what is tv?

Comment: i know that , but you mean that i declare and initialize tv in my main class and use it in another class (async) ?

Comment: you make asyntask on same class and initialize globally